# Handling DB connection in .net-core

Tags: database, web-applications, .net-core

I am working on a ASP.NET Core Web Application, and need a way to store a database connection throughout a request.

In a non-core web application, I would store the SqlConnection in HttpContextFactory.Current. This enabled me to close the connection from Global.asax.Application_EndRequest().

How do I go about getting something to work similar to this in a .NET core web application?

I am not using Entity.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A [mcve] should help clarify the actual problem

Comment: I guess what I am looking for, is a pattern for using a non-entity database connection in .NET-Core.